# What is difference in <? and <?php

Tags: php, apache

I've got some old legacy code written in PHP 5.3.

All PHP blocks in this code are like

```
<? some_php_code_here ?>
```

and my Apache just ignores them, while works good with

```
<?php some_php_code_here ?>
```

Why old code contains invalid blocks, and why this old code works good on old server ? It's really hard to google something with so much special symbols, sorry for stupid question

Comment: to work in `<? ?>` way you have to enable `shorttag` in `php.ini`. But it is not recommended.

Comment: `<?` only works if you set `short_opentag` to `on` in `php.ini`. Generally `<?php` is recommended.

Comment: It might help you to start reading the documentation of the tools you use. You cannot program without looking into the documentation. At least not in a somewhat efficient and successful manner.

Comment: I am just learning new language keep calm and ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?` is called a php short tag

Here is what the **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)** has to say about it

> PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it
>   is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini
>   configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the
>   --enable-short-tags option).

You can enable them at runtime with `<?php ini_set('short_open_tag',1) ?>`

But if you do so you won't be able to use inline xml like so `<?xml ?>`
and instead you can use

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>
```

As a side note I do often use:

```
<a href="<?= "$hello_url" ?>"><?= "Hello world" ?></a>
```

`<?= 'foo' ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo 'foo' ?>` and looks much cleaner in template files in my opinion

Since php version 5.4, `<?=` is no longer tied to `short_open_tag` but prior to that it was, so care should be taken if you might be running your code on older php versions